# How do I iterate over elements with the same ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to programmatically assign the same event listener to two buttons that have the same ID. The problem is when I duplicate the editable content div (the DOM element updated by the event listener) like below, only the first button works and the second button on the duplicate element does nothing.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xo0Lampn/

**HTML**

```
<!---Non-duplicate element--->
<div class="mainEdit">

<!---This one is working--->
<a id="editBtn" class="editbtn" href="#">Edit Text</a>
<!---This one is working--->

<div id="textEdit">Editable Content</div>

</div>
<!---Non-duplicate element--->



<!---Duplicate of above--->
<div class="mainEdit">

<!---This one is not working--->
<a id="editBtn" class="editbtn" href="#">Edit Text</a>
<!---This one is not working--->

<div id="textEdit">Editable Content</div>

</div>
<!---Duplicate of above--->
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var edbtn = document.getElementById("editBtn");
    var edtext = document.getElementById("textEdit");

    // I've tried to loop them but this doesn't work.
    // for (var i = 0; i < edbtn.length; i++) {
    edbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (edtext.contentEditable == "true") {
            edtext.contentEditable = "false";
            var v = edtext.clientWidth + 10;
            edtext.style.width = v + "px";
            edtext.style.textDecoration = "none";
            edbtn.innerHTML = "Edit Text";
        } else {
            edtext.contentEditable = "true";
            edtext.style.width = "auto";
            edtext.style.textDecoration = "underline";
            edbtn.innerHTML = "Done";
        }
    });
    // }
```

I want both buttons to be functional like the first one and when I click on each button, it should make the element with the id="textEdit" editable.

I might be doing it all wrong but I hope you guys can give a solution.

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: The values of "id" attributes should be unique on the page. Having two elements with the same id is an error, in other words.

Comment: @blex—yes, you can. It's just not compliant with W3C HTML and DOM standards. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use duplicate IDs. This is not valid HTML. Consider using `class` instead, in which case you could find your elements with [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassNameHere');

for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function(event) {
    var button = event.currentTarget;

    // Do your contentEditable checks here
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please give an example on the above elements which I am working on?

Comment: That may work, but the [*name* attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/#attr-fe-name) is intended for only a subset of elements such as [*form controls*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute), [*anchors* or *references*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/#syntax-references) and some others (applet, param, map, etc.), it's not a [*global attribute*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/#global-attributes). Probably better (i.e. more consistent with relevant standards and practice) to use a class.

Comment: Rob makes a good point. You could use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead.

Comment: @basitmate I updated the example to show the class-name approach instead as Rob's right, that's a better route. You should be able to figure the rest out from there.